# Any linter to warn about side-effects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, eslint

With the flexibility of JavaScript, we can write code full of side-effects, or just purely functional.

I have been interested in functional JavaScript, and wanting to start a project in this paradigm. And a linter about that can surely help me gathering good practices. Is there any linter to enforce pure functional and side-effect free style?

Comment: @VinodLouis: As far as I know, JSLint doesn't offer any way to check functional purity.

Comment: Can you describe what you call `side-effects in JavaScript`?

Comment: JS is built on side effects as a feature

Comment: @Justinas: Referential Transparency or Purity means that you can replace an expression with its value everywhere in the code without changing the meaning of the program. If you *cannot* do that, then the expression is Impure and not Referentially Transparent. Or, in other words: the result of a function must be fully contained in its return value and can *only* depend on its arguments. Anything else that happens *beside* that is a side-effect: I/O, mutating state, throwing exceptions, printing to the console, accessing the network, spawning a worker, reading from or writing to a file or DB.

Comment: @Thomas: Well, following your reasoning, bugs are features too.

Comment: @ftor, a bug is some unintended/undesired behaviour in the code you/someone actulally wrote. It's not like CPUs, out of a sudden, stop doing math correctly. Someone using your app/lib in a way that you never intended/saw coming, and therefore never defined how it should behave in that case. Like `Math.add = (a,b) => a+b;`, and out of a sudden someone calls it with a string and wonders that your code can't do 1+1 correctly and returns 11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purity Analysis is equivalent to Solving the Halting Problem, so any kind of static analysis that can determine whether code is pure or impure is impossible in the general case. There will always be infinitely many programs for which it is undecidable whether or not they are pure; some of those programs will be pure, some impure.

Now, you deliberately used the term "linter" instead of static analyzer (although of course a linter is just a static analyzer), which seems to imply that you are fine with an approximate heuristic result. You *can* have a linter that will sometimes tell you that your code is pure, sometimes tell you that your code is impure, and most times tell you that it cannot decide whether your code is pure or impure. And you can have a whitelist of operations that are known to be pure (e.g. adding two `Number`s using the `+` operator), and a blacklist of operations that are known to be impure (e.g. anything that can throw an exception, any sort of loops, `if` statements, `Array.prototype.forEach`) and do a heuristic scan for those.

But in the end, the results will be too unreliable to do anything serious with them.

Comment: Why are `if` statements considered as impure? Because they don't return anything and hence must perform side effects to do something meaningful?

Comment: Yes, that's it. In other words: because they are *statements*. Statements are *by definition* impure: "purity" means you can replace an expression with its value without changing the meaning of the program. A statement has no value, ergo, I should be able to replace it with nothing (i.e. delete it) without changing the meaning of the program. This is only true for NO-OP statements, any statement that actually does anything cannot possibly be pure.

Comment: if has side effects only if its parts have side effects. You can see many ifs used to just decide which value to return. In this case if can be replaced by the returned value (or rather something like a ternary operator)

Comment: @jJ': In languages like Ruby, Scala, Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak, Io, Ioke, Seph, Lisp, Scheme, Fancy, Haskell, etc. where `if` is an expression, yes. But not in ECMAScript: in ECMAScript, `if` is a statement and has no value. Period. If an `if` in ECMAScript doesn't have side-effects, then it has no effect at all. The conditional operator, OTOH, *is* an expression, and *has* a value.

Comment: @Jörg I think @jJ means more complex recursive functions, where each recursive case and the base case is wrapped in `if` statements and perform a `return` statement when the respective condition is met . I don't know if Javascript's `return` is considered a side effect in purely functional languages though. So maybe such a recursive function is impure in a technical POV, but its invocation should still be referential transparent.

Comment: @JörgWMittag (as ftor said, but even simpler) function neg(x) { if (neg) return false; return true; } is pure and the function has a value. The fact that "if" is not an expression is irrelevant and being without side effects is a bit more involved and than what you are asserting.

Comment: @jJ': `neg` is externally pure, but its insides aren't. Purity means you can replace expressions with their value without changing the meaning of the program. The value of `if` is nothing, basically, so you should be able to replace `if (neg) return false; return true;` with `return true;` without changing the meaning of the program. But you can't, ergo, `if` is impure. OTOH, you *can* replace `neg ? false : true` with its value without changing the meaning of the program. You can replace every instance where `neg` is `true` with `false`, and the outcome of the program will not change.

Comment: @jörg nope. The definition of pure function is generally very different from what you write https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function. What you are putting forward is just one interpretation applicable only in specific contexts/languages. (e.g. SICP uses it as a possible model of evaluation)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used this myself but I found this plugin for ESLint: https://github.com/jfmengels/eslint-plugin-fp

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use JS commpletely without side effects. Every DOM-access is a side effect, and we could have an argument wether the whole global namespace may also fall under that definition.

The best you can do is, stay reasonable. I'm splitting this logically into two groups:

- the work horses (utilities): their purpose is to take some data and to process it somehow. These are *(mostly)* side effects free. mostly, because somethimes these functions need some state, like a counter or a cache, wich could be argued to be a side effect, but since this is isolated/enclosed into these functions I don't really care.
   like the functions that you pass to `Array#map()` or to a promises `then()`, and similar places.
- and the management: these functions rarely do some data-processing on their own, they mostly orchestrate the data flow, from whereever it is created, to whatever processing(-utilities) it has to be run, up to where it ends, like modifying the DOM, or mutating an object.

  ```
  var theOnesINeed = compose(...);
  var theOtherOnesINeed = compose(...);
  var intoADifferentFormat = function(value){ return ... }

  function(event){
      var a = someList.filter(theOnesINeed).map(intoADifferentFormat);
      var b = someOtherList.filter(theOtherOnesINeed);
      var rows = a.concat(b).map(wrap('<li>', '</li>'));

      document.querySelector('#youYesYou').innerHTML = rows.join('\n');
  }
  ```

so that all functions stay as short and simple as possible. And don't be afraid of descriptive names (not like these way to general ones :))

Comment: It's trivial to define what is a side effect and what is not. You can just check Purescript's DOM/window bindings. And it's not impossible to write JS without side effects as long as the native js/browser APIs are wrapped with monadic effects.

In short: Monads can encode side effects while still maintaining referentially transparency.

But using monads in JS would look like "callback hell" because the language lacks do notation. On the other hand, do notation can be mimicked using generators.